# API Gateway doesn't receive headers from AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS Lambda service to create a serverless function (triggered by API Gateway) that has to do the following:

1. Get the data from the DynamoDB table
2. Create a .docx based on that data
3. Return a .docx document (so that it automatically downloads when the function is triggered).

I managed to successfully accomplish first 2 tasks but no matter what I do it returns a base64 string instead of a document. When I check the Network tab, I always get content-type: application/json in the Response, despite the fact that I specify the headers in the return of my Lambda function. Is there something I need to configure in my API Gateway to make it work? Or is there an issue with my code?

Updates: now the headers are coming and the document download is triggered successfully. But when I try to open it, I get an error: Word found unreadable content. I opened the file in the text editor and its content is the base64 string instead of what I am passing to it. What can be causing this issue?

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { encode } = require("js-base64");

const { Document, Packer, Paragraph, TextRun } = require("docx");
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const params = {
    TableName: 'table-name',
    Key: {
      'id': 'item-key',
    },
  };

  const dynamoDbResult = await dynamoDb.get(params).promise();
  const data = dynamoDbResult.Item;

  
  const doc = new Document({
    sections: [
      {
        properties: {},
        children: [
          new Paragraph({
            children: [
              new TextRun(data.projectName),
              new TextRun({
                text: data.clientEmail1,
                bold: true
              }),
            ]
          })
        ]
      }
    ]
  });
  
  const buffer = await Packer.toBuffer(doc);
  
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="your_file_name.docx"'
    },
    body: encode(buffer),
    isBase64Encoded: true
};
}
```

Comment: Are you using [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html) on the API with configured [binary media types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html)?

Comment: I don't think I am. I am new to AWS and not sure how to do it. I just opened the API Gateway in the AWS console, then Resources tab -> Integration Request -> Integration Type -> checked the box: "Use Lambda Proxy Integration"

Comment: Now the Integration Response box is greyed out and says: Proxy integrations cannot be configured to transform responses.

Comment: Updates: now the headers are coming and the document download is triggered successfully. But when I try to open it, I get an error: Word found unreadable content. I opened the file in the text editor and its content is the base64 string instead of what I am passing to it. What can be causing this issue?